# how to find gsharedinfo from current memory?

Tags: debugging, c, kernel-mode

How would you scann all sections mapped in the local memory context to find `gsharedinfo`?

`gsharedinfo` is not exported from `user32.dll` on Windows server 2008 !!!

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/Meatballs1/cve-2013-1300/blob/master/cve-2013-1300/exploit.c#L16 for a way to find `gSharedInfo` by scanning `UserRegisterWowHandlers`:

```
PSHAREDINFO LocateSharedInfo()
{
    ULONG i;
    ...
    ULONG_PTR pfnUserRegisterWowHandlers = (ULONG_PTR)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("USER32.dll"), "UserRegisterWowHandlers");

    ...

    for (i = pfnUserRegisterWowHandlers; 
         i <= pfnUserRegisterWowHandlers +0x250; 
         ++i )
    {
        if (0x40c7 == *(WORD*)i && 
            0xb8 == *(BYTE*)(i + 7))
        {
            return (PSHAREDINFO)(*(DWORD*)(i + 8));
        }
    }
}
```